# Periodic background task on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, background-process, periodic-task

Is there anyway to run background task on iOS? Like periodically checking some system condition of the phone and report on the widget?

Also, I found that if the iPhone is shut down, then those background task cannot execute again when the phone restart.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: No.
The long answer is more nuanced, but you shouldn't do it anyway. You can schedule your application for background refresh, but that is unreliable (app will not be run on constant intervals), and if user swipes the app in task switcher, the app will not run at all in the background. Another hacky way is to have a server send a silent push to wake the app more reliably. However this is still not guaranteed to succeed; if user swipes the app in task switcher, your app will not run.

In either case, you cannot trigger widget updates from your app. Widget lifetime is managed by the operating system. Instead, implement `widgetPerformUpdate(completionHandler:)` and perform your widget updates there. However, as above, this is not a periodic operation.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is clear. 

If the app is always at the background (assume the user will not swipe it), can i do some periodic task still? i.e., Any method to cause the app to run some codes when it is inactive.

Comment: If the user does not swipe it, your best bet is a silent push notifications (a payload with only `contentAvailable: 1`). This will wake the app and allow you to run.

Comment: If the above is the case, i  am wondering how apps such as Runkeeper starts off audio at predefined intervals even when the app is in the background