# Flutter workmanager schedule background work on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter-workmanager

I would like to run dart code a few times a day regardless of whether the app is open or terminated. I have looked into [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) library and I have a couple things that I don't understand about iOS. The library says "This plugin allows you to schedule background work on Android and iOS." But in the [iOS Setup](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/blob/main/IOS_SETUP.md) it says "Periodic tasks are available on Android only for now!". What does this mean? Is the iOS limited for running a single background task after user has closed the application? What are the libraries limitations when user has closed (terminated) app on iOS device?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Periodic background task on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160088/periodic-background-task-on-ios)

Comment: That is 6 years old answer and the workmanager library makes it sound like scheduled background work is possible for iOS. I would like to better understand what the workmanager library is capable of doing.

Comment: To me it's clear that "iOS [only] supports One off tasks with a few basic constraints". When it says "This plugin allows you to schedule background work on Android and iOS" it's not saying it allows you to schedule *periodic* background work on Android and iOS.

Comment: Is there something which prevents me to create a new registerOneOffTask at the end of the first task?

Comment: I don't think so, but the rationale behind iOS not allowing this is that you can't have "background services" in iOS. If user kills the app in app switcher, it will also kill whatever background task it is running.

Comment: Aa okay! Thank you! So is it impossible for me to run some dart code on iOS couple of times a day if the user has killed the app?

Comment: It is, but the problem is not Flutter, you would not be able to do it natively too

Answer (score 0):

Workmanager only supports *one-off* tasks on iOS. It is pretty clear on that in its documentation.

Moreover, don't expect your tasks to execute when the app is terminated from the app switcher.

iOS decides when to assign threads for your process based on things such as battery life, if the device is awake or not, and now even has ML models that learn from the past performance of your app and your usage patterns. You can't reliably predict when your task gets picked from the queue.

In my case, I had some computation to do at certain times in the day and send a notification. I just moved all of that computation to the server and sent remote notifications.